# sort list of nested tuples by tuple nth element using itemgetter or faster method than lambda

Tags: python, sorting

I have code which is heavy on sorting lists of nested tuples, so a large portion of the run time is spent sorting. The `operator.itemgetter` has sped up the simple sorts, but can't seem to figure out its implementation for sorting on the nested tuples nth item, as `list.sort(key = lambda x: x[1][n])` method works, for example.

Example data below;

```
import random

v1 = random.sample(range(1, 100), 10)
v2 = random.sample(range(1, 100), 10)
v3 = random.sample(range(1, 100), 10)
v4 = random.sample(range(1, 100), 10)
out = zip(v1, zip(v2, v3, v4))
[(18, (68, 11, 71)),
 (72, (24, 3, 79)),
 (2, (1, 84, 69)),
 (24, (94, 79, 17)),
 (19, (67, 76, 19)),
 (44, (79, 12, 34)),
 (42, (11, 33, 92)),
 (90, (18, 52, 47)),
 (65, (73, 59, 70)),
 (95, (74, 85, 60))]
```

If I wanted to sort by each tuples second item (a tuple in this case) I can use;

```
import operator
out.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1))
[(2, (1, 84, 69)),
 (42, (11, 33, 92)),
 (90, (18, 52, 47)),
 (72, (24, 3, 79)),
 (19, (67, 76, 19)),
 (18, (68, 11, 71)),
 (65, (73, 59, 70)),
 (95, (74, 85, 60)),
 (44, (79, 12, 34)),
 (24, (94, 79, 17))]
```

If I wanted to sort by each tuples second item (a tuple in this case) AND that items second element I can use;

```
out.sort(key = lambda x: x[1][1])
[(72, (24, 3, 79)),
 (18, (68, 11, 71)),
 (44, (79, 12, 34)),
 (42, (11, 33, 92)),
 (90, (18, 52, 47)),
 (65, (73, 59, 70)),
 (19, (67, 76, 19)),
 (24, (94, 79, 17)),
 (2, (1, 84, 69)),
 (95, (74, 85, 60))]
```

Can this be done using `itemgetter`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, `itemgetter` does not provide a mode like that. You could, however, define your own, using, e.g., `functools.partial` and `reduce`:

```
>>> from functools import *
>>> deep_get = lambda *indices: partial(reduce, lambda x, i: x[i], indices)
>>> deep_get(1, 1)(out[0])
89
>>> sorted(out, key=deep_get(1, 1))
[(27, (56, 12, 88)),
 (71, (9, 22, 25)),
 (54, (35, 24, 93)),
 (98, (44, 31, 48)),
 (55, (37, 55, 44)),
 (65, (93, 58, 81)),
 (13, (25, 68, 78)),
 (14, (96, 70, 38)),
 (66, (50, 86, 15)),
 (33, (52, 89, 83))]
```

Note that this is *slower* than your `lambda`, though, but maybe more versatile for varying levels of nesting. If it's just about speed, you should just replace your `lambda` with a "proper" function `def get(x): return x[1][1]`, that seems to be as fast as `itemgetter` (on my system, sorting `out` takes 1.3µs with `itemgetter` (one level) or `def get`, 1.7µs with `lambda`, and 3µs with `deep_get`).

```
def get(x): return x[1][1] # faster than lambda
sorted(out, key=get)
```

Comment: thanks. just did a simple test and seems slower than using the lambda function. my hope is that there is a faster function than the using the lambda.

Comment: @matman9 Yes, did not expect it to be. I thought it was more about the interface, and e.g. being able to pass a variable number of parameters / indices. If this is primarilly about speed, maybe you should point this out in the question.

Comment: @matman9 If it's just about speed, you could `def` a proper function instead of using `lambda`, that seems to be as fast as `itemgetter`.

Comment: that's good, not quite following how to replace the lambda, please could you expand your answer to show how. thanks

Comment: awesome, thanks! seems to be even quicker when executed as 'out.sort(ket=get)'

Comment: @matman9 Probably, yes, since `out.sort` sorts in-place while `sorted(out)` creates a new sorted list. For showing the results, and even more for timing, `sorted` is more useful, but if `out.sort` works for you, use it.